# How can I wrap a paragraph on a Cucumber report?

Tags: cucumber

How can I wrap a paragraph on a Cucumber report ?

I have a Cucumber report and I am printing text on the report using:

```
puts "whatever i want to say"
```

In cases when that string is very long, the paragraph doesn't wrap on the HTML report.  Is there a way I can get the puts output to wrap whenever the output is really long?

I print on the report using this:

```
Then(/^show me the api response$/) do
  unless @response
    @response = 'null'
  end
  puts "res: <br/><div style=\"div {word-break: break-all;}\">" + @response.to_s + "</div>"
end
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the answer. Here was my final code:

```
Then(/^show me the entire api response$/) do
  unless @response
    @response = 'null'
  end
  puts "API RESPONSE: " + @response.to_s.scan(/.{1,160}/).join("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts <any_long_value>.to_s.scan(/.{1,256}/).join("\n")
```

where 1,256 defines the number (256) of characters you want before wrapping.